# css scale top image horizontal and vertical but bottom image only width

Tags: html, css

I currently have a modal which i want to use as overlay over webpage.

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>         
      <div class="imgCon">
        <img class="overlayimg" src="img/trendoverlay.png" />
        <img class="overlayimg" src="img/trendtimeline.png" style="display: block"/>
      </div>          
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  width:100%;
}

.imgCon{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 51.5px 73px;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlayimg{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

However here's the problem. The first image(top one) when only image. It's perfect. It works fine.

The image that goes underneath has to stay inside the same DIV as the other image, be as wide as the upper image. But height is fixed. Is there a way to achieve this so they still scale with the padding of 51.5px left/right and 73px at bottom?

picture with more info:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg7hB.png)

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4n1quv9n/1/#&togetherjs=sT7KVDhPT8

As you can see the top image scales how I want it to scale. That it keeps it's aspect ratio but had a minimum left/right and bottom. The image underneath the one is suppose to have the same width as the top image. But the height has to be fixed at 110px. But the Div which contains the images must keep the padding at those 2 minimum at the sides and bottom.

This is going wrong:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPP0P.jpg

Here the bottom image must also scale as wide as the top image. And actually they also need to stick together so it looks like 1 image instead of 2 seperate ones.

Comment: Can you attach picture of what is wrong

Comment: yep, difficult to understand what you want to achieve here

Comment: Make a fiddle or codepen

Comment: Making the windows smaller from left to right is what it's suppose to do. But when sliding it smaller upwards the bottom image stays the same.

Comment: is this what you need -- https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/4n1quv9n/2/

Comment: Not exactly. The images have to stay inside the screen. No scrollbar. If you delete the 2nd image. The grey image does _exactly_ what I want it to do. But I need the red one to stay _inside_ the DIV. and sort of "connect" to the upper image. and use his width.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a Try

**CSS**

```
body{
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
div.image-container{
  position: absolute;
  margin:auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 51.5px 73px;
  text-align: center;
}

img{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-container">
      <img src="http://imgur.com/c7uASdV.png">
      <img src="http://imgur.com/60d6BUt.png" style="height: 110px">
  </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/4n1quv9n/3/)

Comment: May I ask why you using position? It seams like it works without.

Comment: When i change the screen to a wide window with a minimal height. It gets a scroll bar and the image is not resized with the 73px padding at the bottom. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to `display:table` properties to draw a cell at middle to hold and resize first image, and `absolute` positionning for second image :

```css
#modal {
  display: table;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding-bottom: 73px;/* bottom limits */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#modal:before,
#modal:after {
  content: '';
  padding-left: 51px;/* sides limits ... pixel cannot be cut in hlves */
  display: table-cell;
}

.modchild {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 100px;/* room for img 2 */
  width: 1%; /* will expand to fit image width and will stand at middle */ 
}

img[src*="x212"] {
  height: 100vh;/* size it */
  max-height: calc(100vh - 100px - 73px);/* downsize to use */
  display: block;/* or reset vertical-align*/
}

img[src*="x100"] {/* size and stretch it */
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
}
* {margin:0;}
```

```html
<div id=modal>
  <div class=modchild>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x212&text=keep_ration" />
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x100/ff0&text=distort" />
  </div>
</div>
```

fiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/4n1quv9n/4/

Comment: I like the way it works when resizing on the Y axis. But on the X axis if you resize it widens. I need the aspect ratio of the image to stay the same.

Comment: @Toofle first image does keep ratio, second will obviously not. other lead if croping image is not a trouble, object-fit could do preserving ratio but cutting off parts of image (sides to cut off can be chosen from css )

Comment: It works almost good now. But when I make it "tall but small in width" It gets a horizontal scrollbar. Here it's also suppose to scale. Just like in my example the grey block does. Is this possible?

Comment: @Toofle for the horizontal scrollbar , it is also due the display:table properties, it expands to fit content. width of image could be contained too , but then distorsion will show up  `max-width:calc(100vw - 102px)` https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZJGGbN

Comment: Is there a way around this? To avoid the "keep ratio" from not keeping it's ratio? The Distort image is exactly how I need it to be.. I'm also trying it myself but I can't seem to figure it out.